# Copy multiple files to different directories in Makefile

Tags: copy, makefile, echo, xargs

I have a Makefile where I currently have two files that should be copied to different directories. Currently, I've tested

```
echo ${dirs} | xargs -n 1 cp ${sources}
```

So I understand that this will not work since it will try to copy both source files to one of the directory every time. But is there a way that I can execute the copy command for every source file and directory each?

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: `${dirs}` and `${sources}` are parallel lists of input files and target directories?

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to copy each file to a different directory, or each file to each directory?

Comment: @EtanReisner I will answer for the OP :)  : not necessarily.  Let's just say, he has to know what he wants to end up with.  That means, what copies he wants where, maybe multiple copies of some files, and perhaps, no copies of other files. And he knows where the sources are.  Now he wants some `Make` magick to get from the latter to the former.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was unclear with what I want. But yes `${dirs}` and `${sources}` are parallel list of input files and targets. Lets say, I have 2 files, _file1_ and _file2_ and I want to copy _file1_ to _directory1_ and _file2_ to _directory2_. @EtanReiser @Beta @MarkGaleck

Comment: @FluxxSimon my solution works in your case, and in the more general case where you want to copy some files some places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to deduce what you want from what you wrote, but as others pointed out, you should be more clear, so we don't have to spend time deducing it.

Anyway, since you want to not copy all files to all directories, you must somehow tell `Make` where you want to copy which files.  The easiest way is to list the full paths of the copies you want in a variable such as `$(COPIES)`, and not just `${dirs}`.  In this answer I am going to assume the destination directories already exist.

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(COPIES)

PERCENT := %

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(COPIES): %: $$(filter $$(PERCENT)/$$(notdir $$*), $(sources)) Makefile
    cp $< $@
```

Comment: Alright! Actually, the file should be copied and created in the directory. So lets say I have the full path to the file I want to copy as tmp/conf/file1.conf and I want to copy it to tmp/conf/prod.conf. In this case the file _prod.conf_ does not exist from the beginning but should be created when the file is copied.

Comment: @FluxxSimon Then accept this answer as it solves the problem as you stated it, including based on the effects of your attempt to solve it.  Then post a different question, precise this time, and I will show you how to do it.